# Change commit message when using GitHub merge queue

Tags: github

When setting up a branch in my repository to use [GitHub's merge queue](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-a-merge-queue), how can I edit the commit message from within my pull request?

When using e.g., "squash merge" rule for pull requests in my repository without merge queues, I'm given the option to edit the commit message that will be used before merging my pull request. However, with GitHub merge queue I can't see any such option. The commit message is instead always the default message and I haven't found a way to customize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, I don't think that you can fully customize the commit message before adding the PR to merge queue.

You can only edit the default message, and choose to use the PR title and/or description.

Excerpt from this [changelog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-23-new-options-for-controlling-the-default-commit-message-when-merging-a-pull-request/):

> From repository settings, a maintainer or admin can choose the default format for commit messages produced when merging pull requests:
>
> - For merge commit merging:
>
>   - Default message: pull request number and head branch on the first line; pull request title on the third line
>   - Pull request title: pull request title and number on the first line
>   - Pull request title and description: pull request title and number on the first line; pull request description starting on the third line
> - For squash merging:
>
>   - Default message: commit title and commit message (if the pull request contains a single commit), or the pull request title and number and list of commits (if the pull request contains multiple commits)
>   - Pull request title: pull request title and number on the first line
>     Pull request title and commit details: pull request title and number on the first line; commit message (if a single commit) or list of commits (if multiple commits)
>   - Pull request title and description: pull request title and number on the first line; pull request description starting on the third line

You can follow this [feature request](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/15925) in the GitHub Discussions about the merge queue feature in order to be notified when the feature is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a finer control on your commit message template, you could leverage [Mergify merge queue](https://mergify.com/merge-queue).

It offers a [`commit_message` option](https://docs.mergify.com/actions/merge/#commit-message), which allows you to define a template message when merging your pull requests.
You can't do that on a per-pull request basis, but if you define your rules correctly, you can use one commit message template for each use case if you have multiple.